# Can not Activate Site Feed feature of my site collection

Tags: my-site, site

When I'm trying to activated Site Feed feature. I've got this error . An unexpected error has occurred. Any body can help me ?

Comment: Please check the logs to get detailed error.

Comment: How can I check logs? I see DETAILS ERROR link but, when I click it, nothing happen :|

Comment: check with the correlation id given.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS in SP2010. C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS in SP 2013

Comment: You have multiple ways to review the logs. You could go to the log folder as stated above, you can use a program like UlsLogViewer or a powershell comand (es: "get-splogevent -starttime (get-date).addminutes(-1) | fl message > c:\errors.txt" would dump the latest minute of log to the file errors.txt). Any method you chose, we need the log info - real error message - to debug the problem.

Comment: There has been a bug where this feature can not be activated with PowerShell, but I trust you use the GUI?

Comment: Robert: Yep. I use GUI to activate it
Aanchal & SPArchaeo : in LOGS folder, there are many files in there. which file should I open?

Comment: most recent one. But if you are totally new to sharepoint log I suggest you use this program ( [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44020) ). If you open the File menu and chose Open From>ULS it will start displaying the real time feed of logs. Then you just need to replicate the error and see if anything suspect pops up in the feed when you do that.

Comment: For added simplicity if the UI displays a correlation ID you can use that to filter the logs displayed in the feed.